# Next.js TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') now working in component only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to transfer reusable code into a component that has map in it.

I have first made it work in the index.js and /blog/index.js

```
import fs from "fs"
import * as path from "path"
import matter from "gray-matter"
import Link from "next/link"
import Image from "next/image"


export default function Home( { posts } ) {
  return (
    <div className="mt-5">
        <div className="font-semibold text-2xl flex flex-auto justify-center">
            <div className="bg-orange-400 p-5 rounded-3xl">All Posts:</div></div>
      {posts.map((post, index) => (
        <Link href={'/blog/' + post.slug} passHref key={index}>
          <div className="mt-3 cursor-pointer text-center">
            <div className="m-2">
            <h1 className="text-center">{post.frontMatter.title}</h1>
            <p className="mt-3 text-center">{post.frontMatter.description}</p>
            <p className="mt-3 text-center">{post.frontMatter.date}</p>

            </div>
            <div className="p-5">
              <Image className="rounded-3xl" src={post.frontMatter.thumbnailUrl} alt={post.frontMatter.title} width={500} height={500} />
            </div>

          </div>
        </Link>
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join('src', 'posts'))

  const posts = files.map(filename => {
    const markdownWithMeta = fs.readFileSync(path.join('src', 'posts', filename))
    const { data:frontMatter } = matter(markdownWithMeta)
     
    return {
      frontMatter,
      slug: filename.split('.')[0]
    }
  })

  return {
    props: {
      posts
    }
  }
}
```

Now that I am trying to make it work in the component it is not working and throws an error. I know that I can use posts?.map but it doesn't get me to the result, it only throws an empty page.

My BlogPosts2.jsx code

```
import fs from "fs"
import * as path from "path"
import matter from "gray-matter"
import Link from "next/link"
import Image from "next/image"



const BlogPosts2 = ( {posts} ) => {
  return (
    <div className="mt-5">
        <div className="font-semibold text-2xl flex flex-auto justify-center">
            <div className="bg-orange-400 p-5 rounded-3xl">All Posts:</div>
        </div>
      {posts.map((post, index) => (
        <Link href={'/blog/' + post.slug} passHref key={index}>
          <div className="mt-3 cursor-pointer text-ce1nter">
            <div className="m-2">
            <h1 className="text-center">{post.frontMatter.title}</h1>
            <p className="mt-3 text-center">{post.frontMatter.description}</p>
            <p className="mt-3 text-center">{post.frontMatter.date}</p>

            </div>
            <div className="p-5">
              <Image className="rounded-3xl" src={post.frontMatter.thumbnailUrl} alt={post.frontMatter.title} width={500} height={500} />
            </div>

          </div>
        </Link>
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join('src', 'posts'))

  const posts = files.map(filename => {
    const markdownWithMeta = fs.readFileSync(path.join('src', 'posts', filename))
    const { data:frontMatter } = matter(markdownWithMeta)
     
    return {
      frontMatter,
      slug: filename.split('.')[0]
    }
  })

  return {
    props: {
      posts
    }
  }
}

export default BlogPosts2
```

Comment: The error is telling you that `posts` is `undefined`.  What do you pass to that component when using it?

Comment: @David As you can see from getStaticProps I am giving it frontMatter passed blog posts that are formatted as follows
```
---
title: 'Benefits of Walking [For Anyone]'
date: 'December 12, 2020'
description: "There has been too much research that showed that walking has a huge advantage to humans"
thumbnailUrl: "/posts_images/solidjs-thumbnail.jpeg"
tags: ['Walking', 'Health', 'Benefits']
---
```

Comment: is `BlogPosts2` a page component? If not, note that you can't use Next.js' data fetching functions in non-page components.

Comment: @ivanatias Oh... How can I make it work then if I require the component to fetch the data as if it is an on-page component? I mainly transferred it from page HTML to component to get ride of repeatability.

Comment: If you absolutely need that `BlogPosts2` component performs the data fetching, I believe you are stuck with client-side fetching approachs. You could also fetch the data using `getStaticProps` on a page component and pass the props to the `BlogPosts2` component so it only has the responsability to render that data. Don't know if that's what you want tho.

Comment: @ivanatias Thank you, solved it by passing the props from getStaticProps into the component on the server!